# pfSense VLAN tagged and untagged packets on one interface

Tags: vlan, pfsense, unifi

I'm running into an issue here, I'm sure I'm being a fool but after 4 hours thought I'd see if anyone can quickly educate me!

I have a new pfSense. Its going into an SMB client who currently only have a flat network.

I am trying to connect a UniFi AP to the network with a segregated SSID for public use. To do this I am aiming to have on that single port (direct cabled to the AP):

1. Untagged network connected to my management network bridge on the pfsense
2. A tagged network (connected to my public lan bridge) for the WLAN thats configured on the AP.

This does not work.

Testing from my laptop:
If the physical port just has the VLAN interface then it works fine, DHCP, pings etc, all good. This is using the laptops VLAN tag setting to get onto the right VLAN.
If the physical interface just has the management bridge assigned then everything works as well.

If I assign them both to that interface then when connected to the VLAN DHCP does still work but all pings  are dropped. The untagged management network still works with DHCP and all pings etc.

I am at my wits end, the UniFi needs an untagged connection so it can get its IP from DHCP for management but we also need the VLAN on there for the Wifi network.

Comment: Is there anything that can use both tagged and untagged on the same physical interface?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who finds themself here I found the root cause of my problem: There is a limitation in OPNsense/FreeBSD that you cannot use a physical network interface with VLAN interfaces AND an untagged interface in bridges.

Essentially it boils down to a conflict between where the VLAN inspection/processing occurs and the bridge.

https://forum.opnsense.org/index.php?topic=22660.0

https://redmine.pfsense.org/issues/11139

Comment: At least one solution, a configurable switch that supports VLAN, is very inexpensive solution, nowadays.

Comment: In Opnsense can you have an untagged physical interface for normal use and a VLAN tagged interface for guests? Guest clients on the VLAN are not able to contact the router in my case.